# wordpress - memory limit exhausted due to number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress on my client's server . The website has 10,0000 posts . 
When I had less number of posts, there was no issue but now is throws this error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in /home/content/22/11685822/html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 2790

I tried adding the below in my php.ini file ,

> memory_limit = 64M ;

still does not seem to solve the problem .

Kindly help.

Comment: I have faced this when I had used custom taxonomy by using resister_taxonomy and by mistake same `post_tags_meta_box` function called recursively.

Answer (score 1):

try defining max memory in wp_config like this : `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );`

Comment: just below the WP_DEBUG line
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Answer (score 0):

First open your `wp-config.php` which is located in the root **WordPress** directory. Then add the following line inside the main php tag:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

Comment: write this before /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem when I had used custom taxonomy. The cause of my problem I 
did recusive call to `post_tags_meta_box` function (responisible for default tag feature add/update function). If you increase memory limit it does not solve your problem.

Cause of the problem might be leak in your code, or possibly an infinite loop.

So I would sugegst to try to figure out the problem instead of increase the memory size.